# 2 months on the week

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have one problem with android calendar programming, so
If there are 2 months on one week, android write me name of old month. I want him to write something like (old month-new month).

My Code is as follows

```
Calendar wek = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
wek.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,r);
SimpleDateFormat gm = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyy");
mes.setText(gm.format(wek.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does this is because when looking at a date represented by a week, it only looks at the first day in the week.  You'd need to manually check first and last days of the week and, if they are in a different month, then format the date manually. You also need to be careful about the week overlapping the years as well. Something like this:

```
Calendar wek = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
wek.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,r);

//this will set your calendar onto the first day of the week
int w = wek.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int y = wek.get(Calendar.YEAR);
wek.clear();
wek.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
wek.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, w);
//get the month and year of the first day of the week
int m1 = wek1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int y1 = wek1.get(Calendar.YEAR);

//get the date for the end of the week and its month and year
Calendar w2 = wek;
w2.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
int m2 = w2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int y2 = w2.get(Calendar.YEAR);

if(m1 == m2) {
    //if the two months are the same, then just format the date
    SimpleDateFormat gm = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
    mes.setText(gm.format(wek.getTime()));
}
else if(y1 == y1) {
    //different months, same year - format as "MMM - MMM yyyy"
    SimpleDateFormat gm = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    SimpleDateFormat gy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    mes.setTextText(gm.format(wek.getTime()) + " - " +
                    gm.format(w2.getTime()) + " " +
                    gy.format(wek.getTime()));
}
else {
    //Different months and different years - format as "MMM yyyy - MMM yyyy"
    SimpleDateFormat gm = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
    mes.setTextText(gm.format(wek.getTime()) + " - " +
                    gm.format(w2.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And what is the correct month you think? What you do is add `r` weeks to the exact moment of now. This is specific point in time and is associated with particular millisecond. This millisecond belongs either to one or the other month. And your code returns which month is that.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the index of the first day of week, and the last one and check the month they belong to.

(I am not a native speaker but you could say that a week overlaps two months, more than a week on 2 months.)